# Removing quantities in rounds

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem which is as follows:

I have in the beginning 100% of a quantity (say, number of people in a room). Now, I want to remove in the end, say ***p%*** of all the quantity. But, instead of removing the desired quantity of p% in one go, I remove them in ***n*** rounds.

How much of the quantity should I remove in each rounds (let's call this quantity 'x' AND 'x' is FIXED, i.e., in each round, you remove a fixed percentage of the quantity) so that at the end of *n* rounds, I have removed p% of the quantity.

For example,

If number of people in the beginning = 266610

And, I want to remove p = 70% of them (at the end of 'n' rounds)

n = 5 (or, number of rounds)

Then what should 'x' be (quantity to be removed in each of the 5 rounds)? Such that at the end of n = 5 rounds, the number of people = 79983

Can you also explain the process by which you arrive at this formula?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you start with a quantity $q_0$. When you remove $p$ percent of it, you have
$$
\left(1 - \frac{p}{100} \right)q_0
$$
after the first round. When you do it again, you have
$$
\left(1 - \frac{p}{100} \right)\left(1 - \frac{p}{100} \right)q_0 = \left(1 - \frac{p}{100} \right)^2 q_0
$$
Notice how you got a power of two, there? So after $n$ rounds, you would have
$$
\left(1 - \frac{p}{100} \right)^n q_0
$$
If you want the final value to be $q_1$, you have
$$
\frac{q_1}{q_0} = \left(1 - \frac{p}{100} \right)^n
$$
from which you can solve for $p$:
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{q_1}{q_0}} = \left(1 - \frac{p}{100} \right) \qquad
\Rightarrow \qquad p = 100- 100\sqrt[n]{\frac{q_1}{q_0}} 
$$
Is it clearer now? Please keep in mind that $p$ is in percentages ($0\ldots 100~\%$).

---

Plugging in the example numbers, $q_n/q_0 = 0.3$ and $n=5 \Rightarrow p \approx 21.399$ per cent. Then you would have the following figures:

```
 Round  Remaining
 0      266610 
 1      209558
 2      164715
 3      129467
 4      101763
 5      79987
```

The numbers can easily go off by a few units, due to rounding. If you're talking about people, you cannot really remove a fraction of a person ...

Answer (score 0):

First, realise that $p\%$ of the quantity (call it $Q$) is equal to $\frac p{100}\times Q$

We want to remove this quantity in $n$ equal rounds, so each round we must remove $\frac 1n$ of the total amount we wish to remove.

Therefore, each round, we should remove $$\frac p{100}\times Q\times \frac 1n = \frac{pQ}{100n}$$

---

In the example you give, this means we remove \begin{align}\frac{pQ}{100n}&=\frac{70\times 266,610}{100\times 5}\\
&=37,325.4\end{align} people each turn (notice that this is not a whole number so isn't actually practical!)

So, we end up with the following sequence

```
Round    Removed     Remaining
  1      37,325.4    229,284.6
  2      37,325.4    191,959.2
  3      37,325.4    154,633.8
  4      37,325.4    117,308.4
  5      37,325.4     79,983
```

We can see that $79,983$ is $30\%$ of the original quantity so this is correct.

Comment: Nice idea, but the percentage removed each round was supposed to be a constant.

Comment: The way I interpreted it, the amount removed must be constant, my $37,325.4$

Comment: @MattiP. True, the quantity or percentage to be removed in each round cannot change!